# On Erdös's inequality regarding prime gaps

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

By prime number theorem, it is possible to shown that
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}{p_{n+1}-p_n\over\log p_n}\le1,
$$
and I learned from an exercise in Cojocaru & Murty that there exists $0<\delta<1$ such that
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}{p_{n+1}-p_n\over\log p_n}\le1-\delta.
$$
The authors of the book hint that this is achieved using a proof by contradiction (i.e. assuming $p_{n+1}-p_n\ge(1-\delta)\log p_n$ for all large $n$):

Let $q_1,q_2,q_t$ denote all primes in $[x,2x]$. It is trivial that
$$
S=\sum_{1\le k\le t-1}(q_{k+1}-q_k)\le x.
$$
Then the authors say  that breaking the sum according whether $q_{k+1}-q_k\in I=[(1-\delta)\log x,(1+\delta)\log x]$ or not. Consequently we have
$$
S=\sum_{\substack{q_{k+1}-q_k\in I}}(q_{k+1}-q_k)+\sum_{\substack{q_{k+1}-q_k\notin I}}(q_{k+1}-q_k).
$$
Using Brun's sieve I am able to show that the first sum is $\ll\delta x$. This suggests that there exists a constant $A>0$ such that for large $x$
$$
S\ge(1+\delta)\log x\sum_{\substack{q_{k+1}-q_k\notin I}}1-A\delta x.
$$
I don't know how to handle the remaining sum, so I wonder whether anyone in this community can help me complete the proof of this result.

Comment: This result can even be strengthened since we know that there are infinite many prime gaps not exceeding $246$. This implies that the above lim inf is actually $0$

Comment: @Peter I am aware of the deep result, but using this is like using prime number theorem to prove the infinitude of primes.

Comment: @Peter I have posted another question discussing Erdös's paper [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487208/confusion-on-the-proof-of-erd%c3%b6ss-prime-gap-inequality). Hope you are interested